# Have Thunderbird prompt for password at startup for office 365 outlook accounts?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, passwords, thunderbird

I have unfortunately been forced by work to use an Microsoft Outlook / Office 365 e-mail address.

Usually, in Thunderbird on Windows, I used to have normal IMAP e-mail, and I had Thunderbird setup to ask for password at startup, and it worked great for me.

Now, with this Microsoft account, I've noticed it does not ask for password at startup anymore; tried to look a bit into it - this is Thunderbird 115.4.1, and I realized that there is something called Saved Passwords:

[image: thunderbird saved passwords]

So, this is like "oauth" password - and even if I say "Show password", it shows some random string, definitely not "my" password ... and I had chosen OAuth2 as Authentication method because all of the guides online for Thunderbird and office365/outlook recommend it ...

Anyways - if I do "Remove" (password) on this screen - then indeed I'm asked for password at startup - but it is on some stupid standalone screen that looks like this:

[image: microsoft crap]

... and not the usual password prompt I get from normal IMAP. And there's like three screens of it ... and then Thunderbird again caches the oauth2 password, and so it "defeats the purpose".

Is it somehow possible to set up an Microsoft Office 365 Outlook whatever account, so I get prompted for my password whenever I start up Thunderbird - but without me manually deleting the password on every session, and hopefully without going through that stupid Microsoft useless 3-step login screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft365 has moved to Oauth2 as authentication, which creates an app password for your account and ties that to your Thunderbird. This means that you can only login from this thunderbird with this app password, so even if the password is leaked because a hacker got into your computer, they don't get your password, but only the Oauth token, which does not allow them to login elsewhere than your computer.

This also means that you cannot get Microsoft365 to work with a regular password.

So what you want to do instead is protect Thunderbird itself with a primary password.

This means that when opening thunderbird, you have to provide your custom password once, and then gain access to all your emails. Close thunderbird, reopen it, and you have to enter your password again.

The following guide was taken from [ZDNet](https://www.zdnet.com/home-and-office/work-life/protect-your-thunderbird-accounts-with-a-primary-password-and-why-you-should/) (this link contains screenshots):

## How to set the Thunderbird Primary Password

What you'll need: To make this work, you'll need a working instance of the Thunderbird email client and at least one email account configured. It doesn't matter what platform you use for Thunderbird (it's available for Linux, MacOS, and Windows), as the process is the same. That's all you need. Let's set the password.

## 1. Open Thunderbird

The first thing for you to do is open the Thunderbird email client. How you open the app will depend on the operating system you are using (and, in the case of Linux, what desktop environment).

## 2. Open Settings

Click the three-horizontal-line menu button near the top right and click Settings (not Account Settings).

## The Thunderbird menu.

Make sure to click Settings and not Account Settings.

## 3. Locate the Passwords section

Once Settings opens, click Privacy & Security in the left navigation, and scroll down until you see the Passwords section. From there, click the checkbox for Use a Primary Password.

## The Thunderbird Settings window.

You can also view your saved passwords but once you set a Primary Password, they'll be encrypted and will require you to enter the Primary Password before you can view them.

## 4. Set your Primary Password

In the resulting window, type and confirm your new Primary Password. I would suggest not using the same password you use to log into your desktop. As well, make sure the password is strong and unique. Once you've typed and retyped your Primary Password, click OK.

## The Primary Password configuration window.

Since you haven't already set a Primary Password, leave the Current field blank.

## 5. Close and re-open Thunderbird

Close and re-open Thunderbird. When the app opens, you'll see a prompt for the Primary Password. Type the password you set and click Sign in. If you successfully typed the password, Thunderbird will open and give you access to your accounts. If you fail, Thunderbird will still open but will, once again, prompt you for the Primary Password. Until you successfully type the password, you will not be able to interact with the email client.

And that's all there is to protect your email accounts in Thunderbird. I would highly recommend doing this, especially if you work or live in an environment where multiple people could easily access your email accounts.

Comment: Thanks, great answer, helped me understand what actually is going on

Comment: Glad I could be of any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has made some changes to authentication for their hosted email services for business and academic accounts. This post details some of the validation changes that may be helpful to you.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/microsoft-oauth-authentication-and-thunderbird-202

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: it was somewhat helpful, but the other answer is much, much better